# PHP MySql insert gives server error 500

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone tell me why the following code is giving me an error page 500. And also how, can I correct it.

```
mysql_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("xxx") or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "INSERT INTO oc2_ads (id_user, id_category)
VALUES ('$id_user', '$id_category')";
mysql_query($sql);

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Thank you

Comment: what server are you using?

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: You're mixing API's, started with `mysql_*` and then went to some OOP API here `if ($conn->query($sql)`. That'll never work. Not even in Cleveland.

Comment: What does your error log show? Did you define `$conn`?

Comment: Can you see the error log? I'm pretty sure this error is related with how you wrote your query. Just for start, your PHP variables containing the values to be set to do database fields are enclosed in single quotes ('). It happens that there is NO substitution of variable's values when you are inside single quotes!

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Great article!!! on PDO, I will finish reading it when I get home.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: It wouldn't matter if the OP did @chris85

Comment: @EddeAlmeida variables in single quotes *do* get interpolated correctly. You can easily test. [EXAMPLE](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1m3a-ycnv)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single But I'm not the one to discuss the matter @JayBlanchard  . PHP is not my best language and I seldom use it.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Couldn't `$conn` be a valid PDO or mysqli connection and still work?

Comment: It could @chris85, but the connection here *seems* obvious. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yea, looks like you solved; I thought OP might have left something out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot mix database API's. You start with older `mysql_*` functions and then move to some OOP version API (either MySQLi or PDO). If you want to use the older API all the way through you would do this:

```
mysql_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("xxx") or die(mysql_error());
$sql = "INSERT INTO oc2_ads (id_user, id_category)
VALUES ('$id_user', '$id_category')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if ($result === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . mysql_error();
}
```

---

[Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).